# GitHub Actions not picking up Django tests

Tags: python, django, docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to write a simple GitHub Action that runs my Django app's tests when I push to GitHub. GitHub runs the workflow on push, but for some reason, it doesn't pick up any of the tests, even though running `python ./api/manage.py test` locally works.

The `Run tests` section of the Job summary shows this:

```
1s
Run python ./api/manage.py test

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
1s
2s
0s
```

For background, my local setup is using docker-compose, with a dockerfile for each app. The Django app is the API. All I want to do is runn the django tests on push.

I've come across GitHub service containers, and I thought they might be necessary since django needs a postgres db connection to run its tests.

I'm new to GitHub Actions so any direction would be appreciated. My hunch is that it should be simpler than this, but below is my current `.github/workflows/django.yml` file:

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: python:3
    
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      db:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    
    steps:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Performs a clean installation of all dependencies
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r api/requirements.txt

      - name: Run Tests
        run: |
          python ./api/manage.py test
        env:
          # The hostname used to communicate with the PostgreSQL service container
          POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
          # The default PostgreSQL port
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you have solved it by yourself, if so please share your solution. However, what I ran into when doing the same thing as you is that I had to specify the app that I wanted to test for it to work.

For example, if you have your app called "testapp" you need to do:

```
 run: |
          python ./api/manage.py test testapp
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked! I tried running the tests using the app name, and it worked. Before, it couldn't find any tests.